# GitHub pages Jekyll - issues with CSS name

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm a little bit new, but I was curious about changing the name of my main file in my css folder. I have the css folder, where I am importing my partials.

I initially tried to call this base.css and add the following line in my head.html (in my includes directory).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}css/base.css">
```

However, it still would not load the appropriate main css file. Instead, I had to rename my file to `main.css`. there has to be a way around this but I wasn't sure and the literature wasn't that helpful.

Thanks so much! I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of your repo?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Jekyll 3.3, you can use the `relative_url` filter to avoid adding `baseurl`, it should be available for GitHub Pages very soon.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{ "/css/base.css" | relative_url }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prepend option instead:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/base.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

If you are using Github Pages then ensure that config.yaml includes the base.url variable and it points to your repository name, e.g:

```
baseurl : '/my-awesome-jekyll-site'
```